# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol C++ converting Fahrenheit to Celcius

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// declare variables
    string name; 
    float fahrenheit, celcius;
//display greeting
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin >> name;
//ask for fahrenheit
    cout << "Enter a temperature in Fahrenheit degrees please: ";
    cin >> fahrenheit;
//write equation
    celcius = 5.0f/9.0f * (fahrenheit - 32.0f);
//display result
    cout << "Hi " << name << endl << endl;
    cout << "The equivalent to " << fahrenheit << "degrees Fahrenheit is" << celcius << "degrees Celcius" << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is incorrect I have checked so many times and played with the code to get rid of the errors to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is the exact error message?

Comment: 1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Nora\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\lab2T13\Debug\lab2T13.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: I think you need to configure the project as a console project (not a win32 application)

Comment: I'm using win32 as instructed by the professor so there's no changing that

Comment: Talk to you professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an explanation for you

the code you have typed is perfectly correct. It compiles cleanly. But the way things have been setup to complete the process to make a running app ('linking') is failing.

The linker is expecting to find an entry point called _WinMain (hence the error message). This is because when you created the project you said it was a windows app - which its not. YOu need to ask you prof

Also - when asking "why do I get this error?" always include the error in the question

Comment: Wow I feel pretty dumb but happiness trumps all when seeing no errors, thanks so much and sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: we were all noobs once

Answer (score 1):

Change `int main()` to:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

Here's a [Hello World sample program](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/363729/simple-hello-world-in-visual-c-express) to look at.

Comment: @Nora: In that case, use `wchar_t*` instead.